# Excluding rows from second table but including in comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with the same data in it I need to compare one column here is the ddl for testing

```
USE [DifferencesDB]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FirstTable]    Script Date: 11/06/2019 15:27:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FirstTable](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Column1] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Column2] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Column4] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FirstTable] ([Id], [Column1], [Column2], [Column4]) VALUES (1, N'test      ', N'test      ', 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[FirstTable] ([Id], [Column1], [Column2], [Column4]) VALUES (2, N'test2     ', N'test3     ', 18)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SecondTable](
        [Id] [int] NULL,
        [Column1] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Column2] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Column4] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[SecondTable] ([Id], [Column1], [Column2], [Column4]) VALUES (1, N'test      ', N'test      ', 13.56895)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[SecondTable] ([Id], [Column1], [Column2], [Column4]) VALUES (2, N'test2     ', N'test3     ', 18.456 )
    GO
```

As you can see here what I want to do is compare to the two tables and the Data in Column 4 which is a decimal.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT   ABS(T0.Column4 -T1.Column4) as 'Difference'
FROM [FirstTable] T0, [SecondTable] T1
where T0.Id =T1.ID
```

This works but it gives me back tones of extra rows this gets me the difference I require so how do I exclude the rows from the other table.

So, for example, it should say the difference is I would like the data to be returned from the second table but also the difference column as well.

> .456

**Edit**
TO show what is happening on live data.

[image]

Please see my new query here

```
SELECT  GoodData_Lines.Qty,
        Invalid_Lines.Qty,
        abs(GoodData_Lines.Qty- Invalid_Lines.Qty) AS 'Difference'
FROM    GoodData_Lines 
left OUTER JOIN  Invalid_MCSSOPLines 
  ON GoodData_Lines.LineID = Invalid_Lines.LineID
```

Comment: That is the difference only for one row.  Do you know which row you want?

Comment: I want the row from T1 but I need the comparison on both T1 and T0 as per the abs statement

Comment: what is `CAST(30 AS Decimal(18.456, 5))` sql give me an error

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sorry Juan i dont no how that got their i removed it.

Comment: above you have `CAST(30 AS Decimal(18, 5))` what you want to do with second one?

Comment: I have removed it from the script @JuanCarlosOropeza please refresh

Comment: Your expected results don't match your sample data. Also, you should be using `JOIN` instead of that old syntax that is partially deprecated.

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: @LuisCazares amended the data a where the statement is fine and plausible this day and age nothing wrong with a where. A where clause is def, not deprecated

Comment: I still dont see what is wrong with your query. Already 2 answers had the same function. And work ok in this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/befa3/1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I want to display a colum from the FirstTable but if i attempt to it comes back null empty even though their is a matching record their

Comment: You did a great work providing the example. But you dont explain what is wrong with the result. `display a column` is very vague. You have to show us the current result (I saw it on my sqlfiddle) then explain what is wrong and show the correct result. You also mention exclude some rows but never explain what is the logic for the exclusion

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the reason for the expulsion is their identical data but the column in table 2 has the correct data the table 1 column has the incorrect data so I need the difference of both those but when I try it I get 9 thousand odd rows back instead of 900.

Comment: Then maybe add more rows to the sqlfiddle to show the duplicate rows? Because right now I don't see the problem. But again you need take time to explain the problem. You mention `identical data` and `column`. But we don't know what is identical for you or what columns are your talking about. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i have amended my question

Comment: Ok, I see there are `GoodData` without `InvalidData` what is the problem or what you want do with those?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the second qty column is returning null their is data in that column and its correct with the right id as its identical data, i dont get why its returning null i think the left join is getting applied before the output of the columns happen so it then doesnt no their is data in the other column

Comment: Do you know how `LEFT JOIN` works? if you get null mean `GoodData_Lines.LineID` didnt found a match with `Invalid_Lines.LineID`

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution? 
   [EDIT] following your update

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GoodData_Lines](
[LineID] [int] NULL,
[Column1] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Column2] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Qty] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[GoodData_Lines] ([LineID], [Column1], [Column2], [Qty]) VALUES (1, N'test      ', N'test      ', 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[GoodData_Lines] ([LineID], [Column1], [Column2], [Qty]) VALUES (2, N'test2     ', N'test3     ', 18)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invalid_MCSSOPLines](
        [LineID] [int] NULL,
        [Column1] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Column2] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [Qty] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    INSERT [dbo].[Invalid_MCSSOPLines] ([LineID], [Column1], [Column2], [Qty]) VALUES (1, N'test      ', N'test      ', 13.56895)
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[Invalid_MCSSOPLines] ([LineID], [Column1], [Column2], [Qty]) VALUES (2, N'test2     ', N'test3     ', 18.456 )
    GO


    SELECT GoodData_Lines.Qty,
           isnull( [Invalid_MCSSOPLines].Qty,0) invalid_qty,
           abs(GoodData_Lines.Qty - isnull([Invalid_MCSSOPLines].Qty,0)) AS 'Difference'
      FROM GoodData_Lines 
           left OUTER JOIN  Invalid_MCSSOPLines 
           ON GoodData_Lines.LineID = [Invalid_MCSSOPLines].LineID


-- eventually drop table if no more needed

-- DROP TABLE [GoodData_Lines]
-- DROP TABLE [Invalid_MCSSOPLines]
```

Comment: Close but T0 qty is comming as null and not returning a figure it still needs to be part of the calcualtion

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the question was, but based on how I understand it, will this do?

```
SELECT  T1.*, ABS(T0.Column4 -T1.Column4) as 'Difference'
FROM [FirstTable] T0 right join [SecondTable] T1
on T0.Id =T1.ID
```